# Oracle SQL- Most Common Value Over Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out how to return a few values, in addition, a couple of values needing to be indicated as most frequent/common. I have all these values stored in a couple of tables and need to join these tables to each other. Here's what I've got for my statement so far:

```
Select distinct
  W.name,
  D.prprty,
  D.sequence_number,
  D.item_num,
  f.grade,
  f.od_inch,
  count(F.od_inch) over (partition by F.prprty, F.sequence_number) as od_count,
  count(f.grade) over (partition by F.prprty, F.sequence_number) as grade_count
FROM table D,
     table W,
     table F
where D.prprty = W.prprty
  and w.prprty = F.prprty
  and W.prprty  =7000
order by sequence_number, od_count desc, grade_count desc
```

Each property will have values that look like this:

*Property x* 
sequence number:1, item number:1, grade: 10, OD_inch: 2
sequence number:1, item number:2, grade: 1, OD_inch: 2
sequence number:1, item number:3, grade: 10, OD_inch: 1
sequence number:2, item number:1, grade: 10, OD_inch: 2
sequence number:2, item number:2, grade: 10, OD_inch: 5
sequence number:3, item number:1, grade: 5, OD_inch: 2

The goal is to return the Sequence number and the most common grade value and OD_inch value for that specific sequence number, regardless of how many items there are.
Goal:
Sequence 1: Most_Common_Grade: 10, Most_common_od: 2
Sequence 2: Most_Common_Grade: 10, Most_common_od: 2
Sequence 3: Most_Common_Grade: 5, Most_common_od: 2

What do I need to do to my existing query to make sure that it only pulls each sequence number once and it's most common values ?

Comment: please use sql standard joins they are aroud for 30 ears now, you should also use the,

Comment: Don't use distinct -- distinct is an indication that you have written the query wrong - often an indication of someone who is doing a cross join when they should not be.

Comment: Don't use old style joins.  These were wrong two generations ago -- human generations.  In SQL standard generations 5

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, SQL is definitely not my strongest language so take it easy on my syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer because I tried all other recommended solutions and they didn't quite work. Maybe it was the data set or operator error, but this is the solution that provided the best results (Also, forgive syntax issues... Oracle SQL isn't my strongest language and I'm not a hardcore coder):

```
With cte1 as (
select
D.prprty,
D.Sequence_number,
stats_mode(F.grade) as Most_Common_Grade,
stats_mode(F.od_inch) as Most_Common_OD_Inch 

FROM Table D, Table F
where D.prprty != 0
and D.prprty=F.prprty
group by D.prprty, D.Sequence_number
order by D.sequence_number
)

select
    W.prprty,
CTE1.sequence_number,
CTE1.Most_Common_Grade,
CTE1.Most_Common_OD_Inch
from Table W, cte1
where w.prprty= cte1.prprty
order by cte1.prprty, CTE1.sequence_number
```

**(stats_mode was a huge breakthrough because multiple rows would return otherwise)**

Answer (score 0):

Simplified, presuming there's only one table involved: `property`:

```
SQL> select * from property;

       SEQ       ITEM      GRADE    OD_INCH
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1         10          2
         1          2          1          2
         1          3         10          1
         2          1         10          2
         2          2         10          5
         3          1          5          2

6 rows selected.
```

This option requires several steps (read comments within code): count number of rows per each `GRADE` and `OD_INCH` (whatever it is) for every `SEQ`, then sort them in descending order and - finally - return the ones that ranked as the highest.

Note that `row_number` returns only one row; for `seq = 2`, both `od_inch = 2` and `5` rank as "the highest" (as each of them appear once), but - it seems that you want to get only one in final result. If you change your mind, use the `rank` analytic function instead.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    -- count number of each GRADE and OD_INCH values
  3    (select seq, grade, od_inch,
  4       count(*) over (partition by seq, grade) cnt_grade,
  5       count(*) over (partition by seq, od_inch) cnt_od
  6     from property
  7    ),
  8  temp2 as
  9    -- now, sort rows by previously counted values
 10    (select seq, grade, od_inch,
 11       row_number() over (partition by seq order by cnt_grade desc) rnk_grade,
 12       row_number() over (partition by seq order by cnt_od desc) rnk_od
 13     from temp
 14    )
 15  -- finally, select the ones that ranked as the highest
 16  select seq,
 17    max(case when rnk_grade = 1 then grade   end) grade,
 18    max(case when rnk_od    = 1 then od_inch end) od_inch
 19  from temp2
 20  where rnk_grade = 1
 21     or rnk_od = 1
 22  group by seq;

       SEQ      GRADE    OD_INCH
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10          2
         2         10          2
         3          5          2

SQL>
```

---

What would you do, then? Use your current query as a CTE (that would be `temp` in my example), rank rows and fetch the ones that ranked as the highest.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the grade counts

```
SELECT prprty, grade, count(*) as c
FROM F
GROUP BY prprty, grade
```

Now we can find the max for these items

```
SELECT prprty, grade, C
FROM (
  SELECT prprty, grade, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prprty, grade ORDER BY C DESC as rn
  FROM (
    SELECT prprty, grade, count(*) as c
    FROM F
    GROUP BY prprty, grade
  ) x
  WHERE RN = 1
) z
```

You can do the same thing for od_inch

```
SELECT prprty, od_inch, C
FROM (
  SELECT prprty, od_inch, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prprty, grade ORDER BY C DESC as rn
  FROM (
    SELECT prprty, od_inch, count(*) as c
    FROM F
    GROUP BY prprty, od_inch
  ) x
  WHERE RN = 1
) Z
```

Combine it all together to get your results:

```
WITH most_grade AS (
  SELECT prprty, grade, C
  FROM (
    SELECT prprty, grade, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prprty, grade ORDER BY C DESC as rn
    FROM (
      SELECT prprty, grade, count(*) as c
      FROM F
      GROUP BY prprty, grade
    ) x
    WHERE RN = 1
  ) z
), most_inch AS (
  SELECT prprty, od_inch, C
  FROM (
    SELECT prprty, od_inch, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prprty, grade ORDER BY C DESC as rn
    FROM (
      SELECT prprty, od_inch, count(*) as c
      FROM F
      GROUP BY prprty, od_inch
    ) x
    WHERE RN = 1
  ) Z
)
SELECT 
  D.prprty,
  D.sequence_number,
  most_grade.grade as most_grade,
  most_grade.C as most_grade_count,
  most_inch.inch as most_inch,
  most_inch.C as most_inch_count
FROM D 
LEFT JOIN most_grade ON most_grade.prprty = D.prprty
LEFT JOIN most_inch  ON most_inch.prprty = D.prprty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query and then use an analytic function to `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sequence_number, od_count)` to find the frequency of `od_counts` for each `sequence_number` and then use the `RANK` analytic function to rank by that value and use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` find the top ranked rows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sequence_number, od_count) AS cnt
  FROM   (
    Select distinct
           W.name,
           D.prprty,
           D.sequence_number,
           D.item_num,
           f.grade,
           f.od_inch,
           count(F.od_inch) over (partition by F.prprty, F.sequence_number) as od_count,
           count(f.grade) over (partition by F.prprty, F.sequence_number) as grade_count
    FROM   D
           INNER JOIN W
           ON D.prprty = W.prprty
           INNER JOIN F
           ON d.prprty = F.prprty AND d.sequence_number = f.sequence_number
    where  w.prprty = 7000
  ) t
)
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sequence_number ORDER BY cnt DESC)
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Comment: I really appreciate this answer because you’ve taken what I had and helped me do what I was attempting to do earlier. I tried the rank function before, but kept getting errors that the partition needed to be exchanged for “within group”. I’m going to give this a try and hope it works!